# CSS Grid: column-gap forces parent to overflow

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid, css-grid

I want to achieve 12 column grid behavior similar to what Bootstrap has,
but using CSS grids.

1. I need to have a fixed gaps in pixels
2. And have a 12 column grid, so I can decide how to place the children.

I'm facing the issue, that combination of `grid-template-columns` and `column-gap` doesn't shrink the columns on a smaller screens, but cause horizontal overflow on a screen.

How can I achieve expected behavior with shrinking without reducing the number of columns and keeping the gap in pixels.

DEMO:

```css
.parent {
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.box {
  grid-column: span 6 / span 6;
  background: red;
  height: 40px;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, minmax(0, 1fr));
  gap: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 40px of gap *11 = 440px > 300px of your container

Comment: @TemaniAfif
Thank you for answer!
Does it mean that it's not possible to achieve described behavior?

Comment: you can like https://codepen.io/link2pk/pen/bGrJyGZ?editors=1100 
Resource wes bos https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FFwgFpyssjo&list=PLu8EoSxDXHP5CIFvt9-ze3IngcdAc2xKG&index=23&ab_channel=WesBos